# Minus (-) operator on strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators

I was taking [this JavaScript Quiz](http://davidshariff.com/js-quiz/#q=6) and found this question -

```
"1" - - "1";
```

`The result of this statement is 2`.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

I also found that with even `-` the addition of strings take place but with odd `-` subtraction. This only happens when a number is a string.

Here are some more eamples-

```
"1" - "1" => 0
"1" - - "1" => 2
"1" - - - "1" => 0
"1" - - - - "1" => 2
"a" - "b" => NaN
```

Comment: 1 - - 1 == 1 - (-1) == 1 + 1 ... doing a `-` on a string will coerce the string to a Number

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but as a natural next step you may like to read about the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()). `+"1" + +"1"` => `2`, but `"1" + "1"` => `"11"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is equivalent to `"1" - (-"1")`. The unary minus will convert its argument (`"1"`) to a number (`1`) and take its inverse (`-1`). The binary minus will convert its arguments (`"1"` and `-1`) to numbers (`1` and `-1`) and compute their difference (`2`).

Answer (score 6):

As per ecma script [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) :

> **12.8.4 The Subtraction Operator ( ‐ )**

`5`. Let lnum be `ToNumber(lval)`.

`6`. Let rnum be `ToNumber(rval)`.

`7`. Return the result of applying the subtraction operation to `lnum` and `rnum`

**What that means**
In case of subtraction both operands are converted to a number.

So "1" - "1" actually means `ToNumber("1")- ToNumber("1")` but in +, since it's "overloaded" (as java guy would call it), it goes to "concatenation in case of string.